# EC2 spot instance termination notice when downscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I need to run a clean up script every time my spot instance is scheduled for termination. I have two reasons for termination:

1. A price for spot instance exceeds my bid
2. Downscaling caused by scaling policies of autoscaling group (based on average cluster cpu usage in 5 mins, random instance is terminated).

I did like the simple script below I found on [this](http://blog.fugue.it/2015-01-06-spot-termination-notices.html) blog. It covers first case and gives me 2 minutes to clean up before shutdown.

Is there an easy way to get such 2-minute notification for second case?

May be the warning will be available via same url?

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
  do
    if [ -z $(curl -Is http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time | head -1 | grep 404 | cut -d \  -f 2) ]
      then
        logger "Running shutdown hook."
        # Call your shutdown script here.
        break
      else
        # Spot instance not yet marked for termination.
        sleep 5
    fi
  done
```

Comment: But what if EC2 instance is not under Auto scaling group ? In my case, I am using EMR under which all instances are spot instances under task instance group. And, in EMR, there is no concept of auto-scaling group. How can I get notify of termination signal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Auto Scaling Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-lifecycle-hooks.html) allow you to create an event notification that an instance is going to be terminated (or launched).

The up-side: you get a lot more time.  The default is 60 minutes, and you can send a heartbeat message to extend the time, or you can notify the service when your cleanup is done.  If you don't respond, the event times out and finishes anyway.

The down-side: the notifications don't go to the instance itself, as the spot termination warnings do.  They go to SNS or SQS.  You'll either have to subscribe the instance to the notifications (subscribe each instance to the SNS topic on instance startup, for example) or you'll need to roll your own system to manage the messages and communicate with the instances.

Comment: +1 for your reply. Just to confirm, do you think that the notice will not be available on termination-time url?

Comment: I don't believe they will, since the spot instance isn't being "reclaimed" for pricing reasons, which appears to be the purpose of termination-time... but I could be wrong.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll check it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot But what if EC2 instance is not under Auto scaling group ? In my case, I am using EMR under which all instances are spot instances under task instance group. And, in EMR, there is no concept of auto-scaling group.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot [Adding in above comment] How can I get notify of termination signal ?

Comment: @devsda I'm afraid I'm largely unfamiliar with EMR.  I did find [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ChoosingWhattoLaunchasSpotInstances.html), which suggests that "no data is lost" when an EMR task machine on a spot instance is terminated, but am unsure what it precisely means.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did all this investigation. Now, I just need answer of "How to get notify of EC2 instance termination, when its not under ASG ?" 
One helpful link - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/

Comment: @devsda I didn't mean to suggest that you hadn't.  Apologies if my comment implied otherwise.  The link you cited also appears in the body of the blog post mentioned in the original question.  That's the only mechanism I'm aware of for discovering the impending termination of a spot instance -- polling the metadata endpoint.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your help.