# Is there a way to create an Image (AMI) when a spot instance receives a termination request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

Just before a spot instances gets terminated - I'd like to start creating an image of the instance.

I tested and AWS waits for image generation to complete before the shutdown completes.

I also saw this may provide easy access to termination information but have yet to see it on my instance:

wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time

Comment: AWS lambda would be the right solution to automate the task of creating AMI when required. You can schedule the lambda function to run periodically.

Comment: It is easy to schedule periodical AMI generation via Cron. However I only want to start creating an image when Termination is called. I do Not use auto-scaling so I feel this answer does not help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613600/ec2-spot-instance-termination-notice-when-downscaling

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, please as similar questions there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use the termination notice to trigger creation of an AMI. The AMI creation process will not prevent the instance from being terminated, but instance termination should not impact an AMI creation that has already started.

However, I would like to recommend that you do *not* do it.

Instead, you should create an application architecture that does not care about failure. Rather than trying to save the contents of the instance, you should code the system to work successfully even if the instance is terminated.

The best way to do this is to store all data and state **external to the instance**, such as in a database, Amazon S3 or in an Amazon SQS queue. Then, if the instance is terminated and later started again, it can resume its state and continue operating from the last "save point".

This is much like the situation where a computer loses power. When next turned on, it should be able to start up again successfully, recover what it was doing and continue working.

So, try and avoid "old world" thinking of saving everything on a disk. Instead, store the data somewhere that will survive the failure or termination of an instance.

Also, creating an AMI also makes a copy of the entire operating system and application installation. This is somewhat overkill for simply recovering application state and data. By all means launch the instance from an AMI with everything installed, but don't treat AMIs as "backups" -- rather, they are *golden images* that contain everything necessary to run or install an application.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use AWS Backup Service which help to take the periodic backup of AWS resources with more ease and there're so much more with this service. We can have Backup windows, Retention Policy, filter resources at granular level .
Now for the question asked, When the Spot Instance get interrupted, there is 3 option. Hibernation, Stop or Terminate action. In any of the case, when the spot instance get interrupted, we have 2 minutes of grace period to perform necessary action like AMI or snpashot . But, i supposed on 2 minutes, time isn't enough for AMI creation.So, Its better to schedule regular backup of the Spot instance through the AWS Backup Services.

Answer (score -1):

I think [Handling AWS Spot Instance Termination Notices](https://www.fugue.co/blog/2015-01-06-spot-termination-notices.html) is exactly what I wanted. Haven't tested it.